# USB to Ethernet broadcaster

Tags: pic, usb, arm, ethernet

I have an industrial breathalysers that outputs its status via a USB 2.0 OTG port. What might be a suitable combination of processor and perhaps Ethernet chipset. I have not played with the modern PICs and ARMs only the old old Z80s, 8051, 6800 and a few special custom chips.

Or is there a website "symptom checker" where one can specify ones needs and it will suggest a chip. I believe that most modern chips (including FPGAs, not that I intend to use one of these) have devices as added blocks so that the modern designer can keep his or her chip count down.

As the breathalyser is 12 volt I will provide 12 volt to this board with a suitable regulator. I am not sure if Ethernet has any funny voltage or current requirements.
It would be better if whatever chip is suggested has a loadable library of an Ethernet stack (DHCP) and USB driver as no one will pay me to write these. Don't have the time or knowledge yet anyway.

I know that the "Internet of things" is becoming a thing! So there may be new chips or even SOC that I don't yet know about that is suitable.

I will need a programmable chip as some filtering of the status stream will be required before broadcasting the results to servers etc.

The breathalyser transmits its status as a continues stream of cr lf terminated strings. As I don't know different future requirements on filtering, the worst case scenario is a 4800 baud stream of characters that has to be sent to a server. Latency is not a issue. It is to record the value of the alcohol test with a date and time.

Comment: I have found the PIC Microcontroller selector page at http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx

Comment: How is it using usb otg, as a host or slave? Does it need drivers to work?

Comment: There is no simple and general answer to such a question. There are several ways to go, and each has its drawbacks. To be able to give sensible help, you should first tell us a little bit more about the expected communication over the Ethernet network. Amount of traffic, latency requirements, kinds of protocols to be supported.

Comment: Added a small paragraph @LaszloValko

Comment: @passerby It should not need drivers but I may have to learn OTG to see how to decide who is master or slave. Learning curve always present.

Comment: @kingchris: That part is okay, from this, it looks like the amount of resources needed to handle the traffic alone would not narrow the choices available. There is one big question left: what is the communicational model, what kind of Ethernet/IP protocols do you want to serve? There are basically two ways to go: use Ethernet as point-to-point link(s) between your device and your software running on the network computer(s) - that way you have full control over the protocol, or provide standard TCP/IP interfaces (like a HTTP/HTTPS web page) that can be accessed by any computer.

Comment: @LaszloValko It would be better to have full control as one client might want the data sent to a REST url. Another might want the data bundeled into a SQL query to be directly save to a DB. That is always the problem. It might be simpler but not cheaper to buy a Raspberry pie and write code for that. Thanks for the suggestions. Perhaps you could provide an answer that I could vote up.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the TI tiva series devices. They have USB OTG and an on-chip Ethernet PHY. The SDK has example code for Ethernet with DHCP as well as USB. I think they have example code for both USB as a host and USB as a device.

Comment: @alexforencich which chip are you thinking off. I don't see one that has ethernet with it. Unless I am looking at a narrow range of these chips.

Comment: TM4C1294 should have it. That one comes on a decently priced dev board. Not sure which other ones in the line would also work.

Answer (score -1):

If you can coax your device into talking to Arduino over USB OTG, this pre-made solution will work: Arduino + Ethernet shield

Comment: Lol ""pre made""